# Multiplying to powers using recursion

Tags: c, loops, recursion

I am looking for a way to code a program which will multiply an integer to an exponent using only a recursion loop. I have a very limited understanding of recursion, but have been able to code something to give a factorial:

```
int fac2(int n)
{
    if (n == 1){
        return 1;
    } else {
        return n*fac2(n-1);
    }
}
```

I have a way to find a power already, but it uses a `for` loop:

```
int my_power(int x, int e)
{
    int i, total;
    total = 1;
    for (i = 1; i <= e; i++){
    total *= x;
    }
    return total;
}
```

How can I replace this for loop using recursion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function will, to the best of my knowledge, for any likely case (someone setting "asdfj" as x or e is not likely) work.

```
#include <stdio.h>

double my_power(int x, int e)
{
    if (x == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    if (e == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    if (e > 0)
    {
        return x * my_power(x, e-1);
    }
    if (e < 0)
    {
        return 1/(x*my_power(x, -e-1));
    }
}
```

Comment: If `e` starts as `-3`, on the next recursion it will be `(-3-1) = 2`, but it should be `-2`, and then `-1`. Also you need to divide the result of my_power by `x`.

Comment: if e becomes positive, when it goes back through the function it will go to the positive e case. Say we have my_power(2,-3). What the function will do is this: 1/(2*my_power(2,2). my_power(2,2) will return 4, so what the original gives is 1/(2*4), or 1/8

Comment: The `e == 0` special case take precedence over the `x == 0` case, so they need to be switched around.

Answer (score 4):

```
int my_power (int x, int e) {
  if (e == 0) return 1;

  return x * my_power(x, e-1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Remember that a recursive function calls itself until some base case is achieved.  What is your base case here?  Raising a number to a power is liking saying that you are going to multiply some number x amount of times.  The hint is to call the recursive function, reducing the power by one until you reach your desired base case.

Comment: p.s. I didn't add any code as it seemed like you are trying to figure this out on your own.

Comment: That I was, though I kind of figured someone was going to spoil it for me anyway. Luckily, I am still capable of ignoring the ones that give away the answer outright.

Answer (score 2):

Use Dave Anderson's as a basis, but also consider the special cases of where:

```
1) x is 0 
2) e is negative.
```

Again, no code so you can try to figure it out yourself :-)

**Update:** Make sure you create a number of test cases, and you make sure everyone works as you think it should. Once the tests pass, you'll know that your recursive power function is working correctly.

**Example:** Having had time to figure it out yourself, I though I'd present a solution, with tests:

```
int main(void)
{
    // n = 0 special case
    test(0, 0, 1);
    test(4, 0, 1);
    test(-5, 0, 1);

    // x = 0 special case
    test(0, 0, 1);
    test(0, 2, 0);

    // normal use
    test(4, 1, 4);
    test(4, -1, 0.25);
    test(-4, 3, -64);
    test(8, 2, 64);
    test(2, 3, 8);
    test(2, -3, 0.125);
    test(2, -5, 0.03125);

    // Invalid input tests
    std::cout << std::endl << "Invalid input tests" << std::endl;
    test (0, -2, NULL);
    test(0, -4, NULL);


    // Negative Tests
    std::cout << std::endl << "Negative tests (expect failure)" << std::endl;
    test(4, 0, 4);
    test(2, 1, 1);
    test(2, -5, 0.0313);

    return 0;
}

double power(int x, int n)
{
    // check for invalid input
    if (n == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    if (n > 0)
    {
        return x * power(x, n - 1);
    }
    else if (n < 0)
    {
        return 1 / (x * power(x, -n - 1));
    }
}

bool test(int x, int n, double expected)
{
    if (x == 0 && n < 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Testing " << x << "^" << n << ", result = 'Invalid input'." <<  std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    double result = power(x, n);
    std::cout << "Testing " << x << "^" << n << ", result = " << result << ". Expected " << expected << " - test " << ((result == expected) ? "PASSED" : "FAILED") <<  std::endl;
    return true;
}
```

**Output:**

```
Testing 0^0, result = 1. Expected 1 - test PASSED
Testing 4^0, result = 1. Expected 1 - test PASSED
Testing -5^0, result = 1. Expected 1 - test PASSED
Testing 0^0, result = 1. Expected 1 - test PASSED
Testing 0^2, result = 0. Expected 0 - test PASSED
Testing 4^1, result = 4. Expected 4 - test PASSED
Testing 4^-1, result = 0.25. Expected 0.25 - test PASSED
Testing -4^3, result = -64. Expected -64 - test PASSED
Testing 8^2, result = 64. Expected 64 - test PASSED
Testing 2^3, result = 8. Expected 8 - test PASSED
Testing 2^-3, result = 0.125. Expected 0.125 - test PASSED
Testing 2^-5, result = 0.03125. Expected 0.03125 - test PASSED

Invalid input tests
Testing 0^-2, result = 'Invalid input'.
Testing 0^-4, result = 'Invalid input'.

Negative tests (expect failure)
Testing 4^0, result = 1. Expected 4 - test FAILED
Testing 2^1, result = 2. Expected 1 - test FAILED
Testing 2^-5, result = 0.03125. Expected 0.0313 - test FAILED
```

Comment: the first case you give should be accounted for, simply by the fact that anything you give it will just be multiplied by 0. however, the negative one is a bit trickier, and was the biggest problem I thought would come up. perhaps using an if(x>0) {dave anderson code}; if(x<0) {similar, but divide instead of multiply, and add towards 0}. Think I'm on the right track?

Comment: 1) Could be made more efficient as a special case, and avoid any recursion. 2) For each recursion, `e` needs to *move towards* `1`. 3) Dave's example will always return `1` for positive powers, how might you stop that?

Comment: You are almost correct but it's the `if (e > 0) {...}; if (e < 0) {...}` i.e. `e` rather than `x`.

Comment: Looking forward to seeing what you come up with, you're on the right track for sure.

Comment: right- i promise i had it typed right in my actual code. I did find one much easier way of doing it than i had suggested above: if -e, return 1/(my_power(x, -e-1));

Comment: And is that working as intended? See my update - a series of test cases is vital to check your algorithm is working.

Comment: After a little bit of thought, I have come to the conclusion that it is a mistake to special-case the "x is 0" condition.

Comment: The special case of `x = 0` is valid providing it occurs after checking for the most important special case `e = 0`.

Comment: You should have a look at this first: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Powers_of_zero

Comment: @Axn: Good point, 0^-2 is undefined as it implies division by zero - it's vital that this special case is handled as well. In C, this is easiest to handle by preventing the power function from being called where `x = 0` and `e < 0`. Use exceptions in C++, C# etc.

Answer (score 1):

The right way of doing what you want is by noticing that:

- x<sup>n</sup> = (x<sup>n/2</sup>)<sup>2</sup>, if n is even
- x<sup>n</sup> = x * (x<sup>⊦n/2⫞</sup>)<sup>2</sup>, if n is odd
- x<sup>1</sup> = x
- x<sup>0</sup> = 1

where "⊦n/2⫞" means the integer part of n/2 (which is what n/2 gives you in C when n is an integer variable).

Contrasting with the factorial, which reads

- n! = n * (n - 1)!, if n > 0
- 0! = 1

you should be able to write a recursive program for exponentiation basing yourself on the factorial.

Comment: Why are people downvoting this? This _is_ the right way of powering.

Comment: yeah they downvote, they mess with my formatting, where is the police ? ^^

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pseudo-code for you:

```
FUNCTION mypower(number, exponent)
    IF exponent == 0 THEN:
        RETURN 1
    ELSE IF exponent > 0 THEN:
        RETURN number * mypower(number, exponent - 1)
    ELSE:
        RETURN 1 / mypower(number, -(exponent))
```

And oh, the return value should be `double`.

Here's the actual code:

```
double mypower(int n, int e) {
    if (e == 0)
        return 1;
    else if (e > 0)
        return n * mypower(n, e - 1);
    else
        return 1 / mypower(n, -e);
}
```

Comment: Both the pseudocode and actual code have issues with the last line. The correct (and simplified) version would be `return 1/mypower(n, -e)`

Answer (score 0):

There's a way of thinking about this that requires us stepping outside of C-land, but it's so simple at it's heart and powerful it's well worth considering.

Recursion and iteration aren't so different as they first seem. At a [certain level](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-11.html#%_sec_1.2.1), it's actually hard to tell them apart. We won't quite go there, but consider this recursive implementation of a for "loop" (in no particular language):

```
for (i, n, f, a) = 
  if (i > n) {
    return a
  } else {
    return for (i+1, n, f, f(a, i))
  }
```

(The `a`, by the way, is called an "accumulator", because it accumulates the value of each "loop")

The one thing that might be new to you is that the above treats functions like any other data type, which is something called "[first-class functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function)". This isn't typically something you do in C (you can do it in a limited fashion by passing function pointers), but it's so powerful a concept that it's well worth learning.

Using the above definition of `for`, we write your factorial function as:

```
mult(a,b) = a*b
fac(n) = for (1, n, mult, 1)
```

This putts along, multiplying each `i` by the accumulator.

Another powerful concept (that, sadly, C doesn't support at all) is anonymous functions, which are simply functions created without names. I'm going to use the syntax `e -> ...` for anonymous functions, where `...` is some expression (e.g. `x -> x+1`), and `(a,b)` for a pair of variables. In C, anonymous functions might seem useless, but if you can pass around functions as easily as you can pass around numbers, you can simplify `fac` to a single line:

```
fac(n) = for (1, n, (a,i) -> a*i, 1)
```

`pow` can be written as:

```
pow(x, e) = for(1, e, (a,i) -> a*x, 1)
```

Expand `for` in that, and you've got a recursive definition for `pow`.

Though this gives you a recursive function, there is another implementation (Alexandre's, in fact) that's more time efficient.